# Access user location from framework if user allowed the app

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I'm creating an iOS **framework** (using [iOS Universal Framework Template](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)).

I would like to get the user's location (I don't need the exact position, the nearest city is enough). As my framework will be included in developers' apps, I don't want to force apps that don't need the user's location to ask the user for it.

Is there any way I could first check if the developer's app has asked the user for its location, and if the user allowed it, access the last location ? That way, if the app has access, my framework can use it, but I don't force the developer's app to prompt the user to access his location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a boolean property which the developer using your API sets, and this would determine whether or not to use core location.